# Set Display Environment Variable in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, chrome

I was trying to launch google chrome from the terminal in an SSH session and an error occurred saying "**ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(247)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY**". I googled it and found that Display Environment is not set. **How do I fix this?**

Comment: Did you pass the `-X` switch to the `ssh` command? Do you have `xauth` installed on the target system?

Comment: @Bib I don't know about -X switch what it is and how to pass it. I checked and I found xauth is not installed.

Comment: If you don't know what the `-X` switch is, then look at the manual.

Comment: I just checked it out and to do X forwarding we need sudoers rights which I don't have.

Comment: Why on earth does that require sudo'ers rights?

Comment: Ohh I must have read wrong. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: In the past `-Y` worked better than `-X` sometimes. So maybe try that, too.